# How to do scalar multiply on data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I’m sure this one is sitting right in front of me but I can’t see it. I have a data frame, “a”, such that:

```
>a
         Chars    Numbers
This      A        15
That      B        22
Other     C        18
```

I simply want to multiply the Numbers column by a scalar, say b <- 10, and keep the other parts of the data frame intact. (I would get 150, 220, 180 in the Numbers column of the result, but the same row/column headings and Chars column.)

What does not work is a * b, trying to use apply, or a$Numbers * b.

Comment: new <- a and then new$Numbers <- new$Numbers * 10 or a$Numbers <- a$Numbers * 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
a$Numbers <- a$Numbers * b
```

To explain what's happening, let's use the figures from your example:

[image: matrix]

The above code will allow you to use scalar multiplication on the `Numbers` column:

[image: scalar multiplication]

Which you'll then assign back to the `Numbers` column in `a`:

[image: scaled column]

Answer (score 6):

Here are some options:

- `a$Numbers <- a$Numbers * b`
- `transform(a, Numbers=Numbers * b)`
- `within(a, Numbers <- Numbers * 10`

In all cases you need to modify the data frame.  The first method is the most direct, but the other two do similar things.  For the second and third, you will need to save the result for it to be re-usable elsewhere (e.g. `a <- transform(a, ...)`).

Comment: Drats! Just when I think I understand data frames ... perfect answers, both! Thanks!!